# Install Tkinter for Python 3.7 in OpenSUSE

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7, opensuse

I need to install Tkinter in Python 3.7 application.
The Tkinter version for python 3.6 does not work for me

If I do

```
sudo zypper in python3-tk
```

Tkinter is installed in Python3.6.

```
sudo zypper in python3.7-tk
```

not found.

Is there an alternative to running a Tkinter application with Python 3.7 in OpenSUSE?

Comment: This command worked fine for me: `sudo zypper in python311-tk` I was concerned with Python 3.11 :)